# Laravel: Class 'App\Imports\Date' not found

Tags: laravel

I've imported **Excel File** to database **MySql**, but I'dont know why my import display this error "Class 'App\Imports\Date' not found".

This is my controller **VouchersImport.php**:

```
namespace App\Imports;
use App\Imports\Date;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Vouchers;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;

HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

class VouchersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

    private function transformDateTime(string $value, string $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        try {
                return Carbon::instance(Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value))->format($format);
            } 
            catch (\ErrorException $e) 
            {
                return Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `excelToDateTimeObject` this function is available in `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject()` not in laravel export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `use App\Imports\Date;` to `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date`

then it will be

```php
namespace App\Imports;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Vouchers;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;

HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

class VouchersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

    private function transformDateTime(string $value, string $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        try {
                return Carbon::instance(Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value))->format($format);
            } 
            catch (\ErrorException $e) 
            {
                return Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
            }
    }
```